# SharePoint 2016 compatibility with SQL Server 2016 SP 2

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, sql

Is SharePoint 2016 compatible with SQL Server 2016 SP 2 ?

Comment: Check the list of all **[Supported and Unsupported SQL Server for SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-2016-sp1-support-sharepoint-2016)**

Answer (score 1):

It's a supported case.

Check the [https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements#software-requirements-for-sharepoint-server-2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements#software-requirements-for-sharepoint-server-2016) :

Minimum requirements for a database server in a farm

> One of the following:
>   * The 64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
>   * Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RTM
>   * Microsoft SQL Server 2017 RTM for Windows